Is the tangent space of V the sum of tangent spaces of its irreducible components?
I am contemplating this problem. My geometric intuition suggests that this is correct, but I am struggling to prove it. I would appreciate your help with the proof or if you could provide a counterexample.
Let $V$ be an algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}^n$ and let $W_1, \cdots , W_m$ be its irreducible components. For a point $P=(P_{1}, \cdots , P_{n})\in V$, the tangent space $T_{P}(V)$ at $p$ of $V$ is defined by the vector space with origin $P$ cut out by linear equations $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left.\frac{\partial F}{\partial X_i}\right\vert_{P} (X_{i}-P_{i})=0$, $F \in I(V)$. By definition, it is clear that the tangent space at $P$ of $W_{1}$ is a subspace of the tangent space at $P$ of $V$ if $P$ is contained in $W_{1}$.
I hope the following is true: If $P$ is contained in two irreducible components, say $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$, then $T_{P}(V)=T_{P}(W_{1})+T_{P}(W_{2})$. The nontrivial part is to show that $T_{P}(V)\subseteq T_{P}(W_{1})+T_{P}(W_{2})$.. How can I prove it? Or is there a counterexample?
Any idea will be helpful to me. Thanks for your help!

Your statement is not true. For example let $V \subset \mathbb A^2$ be the zero set of $(y-x^2)(y+x^2)$ and consider the tangent space at $(0,0)$.

Yes you are right. I think it is not true if the gradiant at the point is  linearly dependent. Thank you for your help!
